# List of new product on homepage in Magento

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. I want show list of new product in homepage in CE. I want to show image of each product only by hiding it's title, add to cart and others.

How can I develop or customize xml layout or .phtml in my theme?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this.

Go to CMS->Pages->Home Page. In content section add the following code.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

The new.phtml will be in the location ../magentoproject/app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml.

You can make changes in the file according to your needs. As per your request you need to shaow the images with rest of the options hidden. comment out or remove the respective code there in that file. You will get what you need.

If you didn't find the file please go to the base theme of magento, and you will get the code there and make use of this in your theme.

As a sample:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()):
   foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product):?>
      <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(268, 323) ?>" alt="">
<?php 
  endforeach;
 endif;  
?>
```

Comment: ++ for out of the box solution

Answer (score 0):

Goto admin >> CMS >> Pages >> Home Page

Goto Content Tab

Add `{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/newprod.phtml"}}`

Create a newprod.phtml in your app/design/frontend/(package)/(theme)/page/html/newprod.phtml

Add this code there :-

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")
   ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())
   ->setPageSize(2)
   ->setCurPage(1);

foreach($product_collection as $products) {
    print_r($products->getData());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sandeep. But only array i can see. could show detail how to list image with link to product detail

Comment: foreach($product_collection as $products) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId());
        ?>
 <li class="span3">
     <div class="featured-img">
      <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
   <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(171); ?>" />
      </a>
      <span class="darrow"></span>
     </div>

Answer (score 0):

1st. You need to call the specific block that we are going to create in the second step. There are two ways to do that:

1. We can do if from content tab
   Go to  >> CMS >> Pages >> Home Page >> Content Tab - Here you can get the block directly from the content by adding:
   `{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/new_product_example.phtml"}}`
2. The other way is if we get the block from the layout of the home page.
   Go to  >> CMS >> Pages >> Home Page >> Design >> Page Layout -

`<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new_product_example.phtml" after="cms_page">
  <action  method="setColumnCount"><column_count>3</column_count></action>
  <action  method="setProductsCount"><count>9</count></action>`

2nd.This code should go to the new_product_example.phtml In order to do that you will need to use the date that the order was created. The key to display all products information as price, name, and etc. 
   `->addAttributeToSelect('*')`   Here is the script:

```
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
  ->addStoreFilter($store_id)
  ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
  ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)  
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))                          
  ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
  ->setPage(1, 9);
```

After that you can create your product grid.